# Rolling of Dice probability of getting exactly two 3s in 'k' rolls

Tags: python, plot, probability, dice

Trying to calculate the probability of getting two 3s in 'k' rolls and then bar plot.  Prior to me adding the code starting with prob_trials[], it would not return any output.  Then when I added the prob_trials[] code, if get the error of tuple not callable.

```
import random
import pylab

"Calculating probability of getting exactly a 3 in k rolls"

dice=(1,2,3,4,5,6)
one=0
two=0
three=0
four=0
five=0
six=0
for i in range(100):
    result = random.choice(dice)
    if result == 1:
        one +=1
    elif result == 2:
        two +=1
    elif result == 3:
        three +=1
    elif result == 4:
        four +=1
    elif result == 5:
        five +=1 
    elif result == 6:
        six +=1
trial_result = (one, two, three, four, five, six)

prob_trials=[]
for i in range(6):
    a = trial_result(i)/100
    prob_trials.append(a)
    
pltbar(dice,prob_trials)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a direct calculation of the probability. The experiment of rolling a dice getting

1. '3' with probability `1/6`
2. 'not 3' with probability `5/6`

This can be looked as a [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution). Thus, the act of `2` successes in `k` experiments will be regarded as [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). Therefore, the probability of a binomial random variable `X` to have `2` successes in `k` attempts will be computed as:

`P(X=2) = (k choose 2)*(1/6)^2 * (5/6)^{k-2}`

Code example for this will be:

```
from math import comb

p = 1/6  # probability of success in an experiment
k = 8    # number of experiments, put any number here
s = 2    # number of successes, 2 in our case

prob = comb(k, s) * p**s * (1-p)**(k-s)

print(prob)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I expanded to try to plot:import pylab
import random
from math import comb



p = 1/6  # probability of success in an experiment
k = 100    # number of experiments, put any number here
s = 2    # number of successes, 2 in our case

prob = comb(k, s) * p**s * (1-p)**(k-s)

dice=(1,2,3,4,5,6)

three=0

print(prob)

trial_result = (three)

prob_trials=[]
for i in range(6):
    a=trial_result[i]/100
    prob_trials.append(a)    


pylab.plot(dice,prob_trials)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have put normal brackets `()` after the name of the tuple, whereas you should use square brackets `[]`.

In fact, what you probably want to do is simply iterate over the tuple, so that you don't have to index it in the first place:

```py
prob_trials=[]
for i in trial_result:
    a = i / 100
    prob_trials.append(a)
```

Also, `pltbar` is not defined so will give you an error. I am not familiar with the `pylab` module, but I can hazard a guess that what you actually meant was:

```py
pylab.pltbar(dice,prob_trials)
```

(Although I might be wrong)

Comment: Thank you and those suggestion fixed my errors.  If I wanted to change the formula just to calculate the probability of getting two 3's in k rolls, would I remove all code that is not associated with rolling a 3